# Adding Comment Meta to a new comment notification email

Tags: comment-meta

I am trying to include a rating comment meta value in the subject line of the email that notifies authors that someone has left a new comment (and, in my case, a rating) on their post.

```
function mycustomfilter_comment_notification_subject( $subject, $comment_id ) {
        $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );

        $subject = get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . ': ' . get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) . ' star rating';

        return $subject;
}
add_filter( 'comment_notification_subject', 'mycustomfilter_comment_notification_subject', 10, 2 );
```

The `get_comment_meta()` call is failing. It also fails when I try and output the same comment meta data using the `comment_notification_text filter`.

The rating value is being saved to the database as I can access this variable in a custom `wp_list_comments()` callback I have prepared.

Any idea why my email code is failing? Many thanks.

Comment: Not sure about an actual answer, but I do note that `$comment->comment_ID` in `get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true )` is unnecessary as you already have the `$comment_id` variable from the filter so you should use that there instead: `get_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', true )`. Same in `get_the_title()` I guess. Might help.

Comment: Thanks Peter. What actually finally fixed the problem was simply adding a priority number of 5 to the comment_post action that was saving my rating value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a priority number to the comment_post action that was saving my rating value, as shown below:

```
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
    if ( ( isset( $_POST['rating'] ) ) && ( $_POST['rating'] != '') ) {
        $rating = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['rating']);

        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', $rating );
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data', 5 ); // Adding a priority number of 5 fixed the problem!
```